# What have I to do to insert a float value into a database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have the following situation:

I have create a C# method that perform an insert query into a SQL Server database table. Into this method I have something like it:

```
                // [Severity] insertion on the DB:
                if (v.Severity != null)
                {
                    _strSQL += ",[Severity] ";
                    strSQLParametri += ", @SEVERITY ";
                    _addParameter(command, "@SEVERITY", v.Severity);
                }
```

where `Severity` is the table column and `v.Severity` is the value that I have to put into this column for the new row.

On the table the `Severity` column is definied as `float`

My problem is that if the value of `v.Severity` is something like `3.7` it perform `3.7` value into the `Severity` column but if it is something like `3.0` it put `3` and not `3.0`

What have I to do to have `3.0` instead `3` into my `Severity` column?

Comment: `3` and `3.0` are the same number, they're just _displayed_ differently.  You need to change how you're displaying the data to show `3.0` instead of `3`.

Comment: Its also the same as 3.00, 3.000, and so forth. Similarly, 3.7 is the same as 3.70, 3.700 and so forth. An exact floating point value can have an arbitrary number of trailing zeroes. It only matters if it was a scientific measurement (so significant figures are important) in which case you would store the precision in a different column.

Comment: To be even more specific for nice @BradleyDotNET comment: `3.7` is same as `3.700000047683716` because `0.7` can't be represented precisely with powers of 2, unlike `0.5` for example. Check out http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to see how it works.

Comment: `float` is a badly chosen data type for severity. I suggest `int` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Float numbers don't have concept of "important trailing zeros". As result 3.0, 3, 3.0000 are all the same when present in binary form.

If you must preserve value as formatted somewhere - store as string in the database (or any other storage). If you know exactly how many digits you want to be present consider custom type that will store value pre-multiplied (like `3.0` as `3.0*10`, or even `(int)30`) and carefully shift floating point during math operations.

If you just want to display with at least one digit after decimal point - use appropriate format.

Comment: Just to add, I always found it bad practice to mix data and GUI. Your database should contain and store your data (3), but your GUI should be responsible for how it is displayed and presented to the user (3.0).

Comment: @icemanind - good point, there are rare cases when on must preserve exact value as shown to user (i.e. some legal document)... but indeed even in such cases I'd expect value to be stored separately as proper `decimal` (or maybe regular `float`) value in addition to precise text.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of inserting an integer that will be automatically changed to float

```
create table #tablefloat 
(
    Severity_amount float
)

insert into #tablefloat select 212

select * from #tablefloat
```